# How are max current loads measured?

Tags: electric-current

How are max current loads measured?

Does this require that one finds the spot, where the wire e.g. melts?

Answer (score 0):

That is basically the idea - though melting would be extreme.
When free electrons travel through a metal some energy is transferred to phonons - which are lattices vibration quanta.  Macroscopically this is seen as heat and it can burn insulation or melt wires.  Metals such as copper, aluminum and silver have small electron/phonon coupling so they can carry more current per unit of volume or mass.

Knowing the size of the wire and what it is made of allows a calculation of how much current can flow before the heating gets too extreme.  The max current load can be increased by installing cooling devices.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the various types of insulation applied to wires used to carry current all possess some maximum service temperature, above which their insulating qualities begin to break down from heat and their strength degrades. If one knows the heat generation rate of a wire of given size while carrying a given amount of current, one can estimate the resulting temperature of the insulation. Knowing the maximum allowable service temperature of the insulation, one can then assign a maximum current rating to the wire.